# Is it possible to create iterators with C++14 that are C++17 compliant?

Tags: c++, stl, c++14, c++17

I'm using GCC 6.2.0, which uses C++14 by default. At some point in the future, we'd like to move to C++17. I'd like to add some C++ iterators to some of our classes but they've changed between C++14 and C++17. If I write them now, will I have to rewrite them later when we upgrade compiler versions or is there a way to write them once now and have them be forwards compatible?

Comment: I dont really understand. Take pointers for example, they always have been and always will be "compliant" iterators

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of a C++14 iterator that you believe will need to be changed? Are you thinking of using [std::iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator) and worry about it being deprecated? Since you haven't written the iterators yet, just don't use `std::iterator`. C++14 doesn't need it.

Answer (score 6):

The change I believe you where talking about was the removal of the class template `std::iterator`.

`std::iterator` was and always will be nothing but a utility helper; it was removed because it is a simple utility, and because people where assuming it was more than just a utility helper.

Don't use `std::iterator`, just define the typedefs yourself.

If updating a code base that already uses `std::iterator`, create your own (it is like 6 lines of code) and search/replace.